# Error while inserting date column into oracle database using odbc package in R

Tags: r, oracle, odbc, dbi

we are using odbc connection to connect target database (oracle database) and we need to insert a dataframe into target database. We are using dbBind() to insert data frame into database. Please find the sample data and code mentioned below.

```
Dataframe: Inputdata
  column1    column2    column3      date_column  column4
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>         <chr>
1 1111       6          fff          2015-11-01    MCA
2 2222       1          aaa          2006-12-02    NA
3 3333       2          bbb          2007-10-03    NA
4 4444       3          ccc          2008-01-04    NA
5 555        4          ddd          2007-11-05    NA
6 6666       5          eee          2010-11-06    BCH


R script :
Target1Conn<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "TARGETDB", uid = "username", pwd = "password")
insert <- dbSendQuery(Target1Conn, paste0('insert into ', outputTableName, '(column1,column2,column3,date_column,column4) values(?,?,?,?,?)'))
dbBind(insert, list(InputData$column1,InputData$column2,InputData$column3,InputData$date_column,InputData$column4))"

Error:
Error in result_bind(res@ptr, as.list(params), batch_rows) :
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 00000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

My DataFrame has 1.3 million records and with the above approach after inserting 1024 records, the script is getting failed with error mentioned above.

if we ignore date column and insert data , we are able to insert data into database without any issues. Please let us know if any other solution is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>%
    mutate(date_column = ymd(date_column))
```

and then run your code again.

Comment: Hi Georgery,  Thanks for the reply. after executing df <- df %>%mutate(date_column = ymd(date_column)) this command, we are getting below mentioned error. Error in result_bind(res@ptr, as.list(params), batch_rows) :
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 00000: [Oracle][ODBC]Numeric value out of range.   [Oracle][ODBC]General error. ut of range.